# Importing MSHTML_TLB results in 12 Mb source file!

Tags: delphi

Also "generate component wrappers" does not seem to have any effect on if they're generated or not: even with this checkbox cleared when I later add the TLB into the package and install the package, it installs ~ 100 components.

What to do?

Apparently the space is mostly taken by "OLE Server Proxy class declaration" and "OLE Server Properties Proxy Class", of which two are made for every object in the TLB, and their implementation code. Why the hell do I need these? Can I instruct Delphi not to generate them?

Delphi version: Delphi 2007 for Win32 build 11.0.2902.10471

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is your harddisk to small?

Comment: Delphi IDE takes several minutes of 100% processor load only to open the file for editing. Instant help suggestions freeze the IDE for around one minute before appearing. I didn't even try to compile the thing. I'm afraid Delphi just cant stomach this.

Comment: Don't worry about the file's size, there is no problem compiling a project that uses the file.  
After the file is created once, you never have to deal with it again. Or is there a reason that you need to edit it?

Comment: Nope, but instant help (or however the thing's called: the one that shows you fields, properties and methods when you type "." after a class name) freezes each time, supposedly scanning the included files for the identifiers.

Well, I've fixed it by manually deleting the "ole server" stuff. This brought the size down to 1.3 mb which Delphi handles just fine, somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your last comment. I had the same "freezing" problem, but couldn't figure out where it came from. Without mshtml_tlb, the IDE works fine again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing my own question, summarizing the results:

1. Indeed, the bugs are there (both the Delphi 2007 IDE more or less disregarding the "generate component wrappers" checkbox and freezing when dealing with 12 mb file).
2. One solution is to delete the component wrappers from the file manually, then to not reimport it accidentally.
3. Another one is to import the file not through the IDE, but via tlibimp (Delphi command-line tool to import type libraries). This one has a lot of settings to choose from, so you can probably trim the size down.